# Is this statement right?

Tags: sentence-structure

I want to clarify weather we can use years and decade in same sentence to describe the sentence? For example this sentence is correct or it has grammatical error:
 “From years and over a decade education remain the most vibrant factor to decide the future of nation?”
Please answer with logic... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, one would not say "for years and over a decade". A decade comprises of years and so to say both is just *redundant*. It would be like saying "*the journey takes hours and minutes*" - not only is it a tautology but it also detracts from the point of the sentence which may be to state how *long* it takes (hours) or how quick it is (minutes).

If you want to impress on the reader that the number of years is greater than ten but without specifying exactly how many you should either say:

> For over ten years...

or

> For over a decade...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Just want to clear that is it totally wrong or it make some sense as I use it in an essay test....!

Comment: Using the expression "for years and over a decade" in an essay test won't help you get a good mark. It sounds like poor writing, and the readers won't be impressed with it.